# Vapor 2 try block not working

Tags: swift, vapor

Trying to map a post request json to a model and the try block is passing even though I'm sending nothing in the body. Can't figure out why. Code looks like:

```
extension Request {
  func localUser() throws -> LocalUser {
    guard let json = json else { throw Abort.badRequest }
    do {
        return try LocalUser(json: json)
    } catch  {
        throw Abort(.notAcceptable, reason: "\(error)")
    }
  }
}
```

In the model I have the following extension:

```
extension LocalUser: JSONInitializable {
  convenience init(json: JSON) throws {
    try self.init(
        email: json.get("email"),
        password: json.get("password")
    )
  }
}
```

The request line is: `let initialUser = try request.LocalUser()`. I've tried print calls along the process and the JSONInitializable seems to pass through. Thanks

Comment: Which code is not working?

Comment: I believe it's the convenience init

Comment: What are `LocalUser`'s properties? What is the signature of `LocalUser`'s initialiser? What is the JSON you are testing with? Please post some contextual code.

Comment: Local user has the properties `email` & `password`, both `String` types. initialiser is standard `init(emai:String, password:String {self.email = email etc }`. Not passing in any JSON or an empty body of JSON and the issue happens.

Comment: What you've posted looks fine. The problem is somewhere else. _We need your code_.

Comment: Agree with others that you should post more code, specifically the initializer you're calling on `LocalUser` and the property declarations. My guess is that the initializer takes Optional Strings for `email` and `password`, but I can't know for sure.